# setState no Flutter funciona apenas na primeira vez

Tags: flutter, dart

Estou estudando Flutter e decidi fazer um carrinho, tenho o widget produto e o widget para listar os produtos.

O problema é que quando clico pela primeira vez em adicionar ele adiciona no carrinho e atualiza a quantidade no widget na lista de widget,  (de 0 passa para 1 em tempo real), mas se clico novamente ele adiciona no carrinho mas não atualiza o widget.

Se eu troca de tela e depois volto para a tela inicial, os widgets são atualizados

O que pode ser o problema?

---

Widget Produto

```
                       Expanded(
                        flex: 2,
                        child: IconButton(
                            icon: Icon(Icons.remove),
                            onPressed: () async{
                              await widget.cart.remove(widget.produto);
                              setState(() {
                                
                              });
                            }),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        width: 10,
                        child: TextField(
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                              hintText: '${widget.produto.quantidade}',
                              border: InputBorder.none),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Expanded(
                        flex: 2,
                        child: IconButton(
                            icon: Icon(Icons.add),
                            onPressed: () async{
                              await widget.cart.add(widget.produto);
                              setState(() {
                                
                              });
                            }),
                      ),
```

Widget para listar os produtos:

```
class ListProducts extends StatefulWidget {
  List<Produto> _products;
  ListProducts(this._products);

  @override
  _ListProductsState createState() => _ListProductsState();
}

class _ListProductsState extends State<ListProducts> {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: widget._products.length,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctx, int index) {
        return ProdutoWidget(widget._products[index]);
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Não tem o código inteiro na pergunta, mas pelo que entendi, você tem dois StatefulWidget, certo? A lista, e o elemento da lista, correto? E você quer, de dentro do Widget interior, dar setState no mais externo? Se for isso, os setState's que você mostrou não vão funcionar. O jeito mais simples é adicionar um callback no widget interno que chama o setstate no widget externo. Além disso, existe alguma motivação pro widget interior ser stateful?

Comment: Entendi, então dentro do widget de produtos eu passaria uma callback pro widget de listagem setar o novo estado? Realmente o widget de produto não precisa ser stateful